# Reddit account creator

Tags: c#, reddit

I'm trying to make a program that will create an account on Reddit using an `HttpWebRequest`. I ONLY want it to do that. (I don't care about it storing a cookie or anything else.) I just want it to be a simple program where you type a username into `Username_TextBox.Text` and a password into `Password_TextBox.Text` and then click the `CreateAccount_Button` and voilà, new account created!

I followed a tutorial on YouTube that poorly explained how everything about a `HttpWebRequest` worked.

Currently, the program **will** create a Reddit account as long as the username hasn't been taken already. I just don't want any excess code that is useless. I want **any** extra code removed that isn't contributing to my goal mentioned above.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace RedditAccountCreate
{
    public partial class RedditAccountCreate : Form
    {
        public RedditAccountCreate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        CookieContainer CreateAccountCookie;

        private void CreateAccount_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string POSTData = "op=reg&dest=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2F&user=" + Username_TextBox.Text + "&passwd=" + Password_TextBox.Text + "&passwd2=" + Password_TextBox.Text + "&email=&api_type=json";
            CookieContainer TemporaryCookie = new CookieContainer();
            UTF8Encoding Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] ByteData = Encoding.GetBytes(POSTData);

            HttpWebRequest POSTRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.reddit.com/api/register/" + Username_TextBox.Text);
            POSTRequest.Method = "POST";
            POSTRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            POSTRequest.CookieContainer = TemporaryCookie;
            POSTRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            POSTRequest.Referer = "http://www.reddit.com/";
            POSTRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
            POSTRequest.ContentLength = ByteData.Length;

            Stream POSTRequestStream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream();
            POSTRequestStream.Write(ByteData, 0, ByteData.Length);
            POSTRequestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse POSTResponse = default(HttpWebResponse);

            POSTResponse = (HttpWebResponse)POSTRequest.GetResponse();
            TemporaryCookie.Add(POSTResponse.Cookies);
            CreateAccountCookie = TemporaryCookie;
            StreamReader POSTRequestReader = new StreamReader(POSTResponse.GetResponseStream());

            string POSTRequestCode = POSTRequestReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
```

[Here's the link to the YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Wzel-g1U54) that I followed, in case anyone wants it.

Answer (score 3):

Some points about your code

- extract the code to create an account to a separate class. In this way you can reuse it without problems. This can even be a static method.
- variables should be named using `camelCase` casing. See the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).
- as you don't use neither the `TemporaryCookie` nor the `CreateAccountCookie` you should remove these varaibles.
- the assignment of `POSTRequest.KeepAlive = true;` is superflous because the default of the `KeepAlive` property is `true`.
- `string POSTRequestCode = POSTRequestReader.ReadToEnd();` is superflous because it is never used.
- because `Stream` is implementing `IDisposable` you should enclose it in a `using` statement. This will take care that the `Stream` is closed and disposed.
- you don't use the `HttpWebResponse POSTResponse` so you can remove it too

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to:

```
private static string postDataToFormat = "op=reg&dest=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2F&user={0}&passwd={1}&passwd2={1}&email=&api_type=json";
public static void CreateRedditAccount(string userName, string passWord)
{
    string postData = string.Format(postDataToFormat, userName, passWord); 

    UTF8Encoding Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] postValue = Encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest POSTRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.reddit.com/api/register/" + userName);
    POSTRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    POSTRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    POSTRequest.Referer = "http://www.reddit.com/";
    POSTRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
    POSTRequest.ContentLength = postValue.Length;

    using (Stream POSTRequestStream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        POSTRequestStream.Write(postValue, 0, postValue.Length);
    }

}
```